# How to catch a signal emitted from derived c++ class in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

My model is in C++ and front end is QML. The model consist of an interface class which contain other components. In simplied form (proof of concept stage) This interface class is pure virtual class called `Base` which is derived from `QObject`. I have a `Derived` class derived from `Base`

I am emitting signal in the derived class when data changes. My problem is how to catch this signal and process in QML?

```
derived.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Derived::somethingChanged(void)" (?somethingChanged@Derived@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall Derived::doSomething(void)" (?doSomething@Derived@@UAEXXZ)
```

My Base.h class is:

```
#include <QObject>

class Base : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Base(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Base();

    virtual void doSomething() = 0;

signals:

public slots:
};
```

Derived.h is

```
#include "base.h"

class Derived : public Base
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Derived();
    ~Derived();

    virtual void doSomething();

signals:
    void somethingChanged();
};
```

Derived.cpp is

```
#include "derived.h"

#include <QDebug>

Derived::Derived()
{

}

Derived::~Derived()
{

}

void Derived::doSomething()
{
    qDebug() << "doSomething() called in Derived";

    emit somethingChanged(); // this doesn't compile!
}


Connections {
    target: What? // what should I put here, 
    onSomethingChanged: console.log("The application data changed!")
}
```

Again the problem is what do I put for `target` property? The model will only expose the interface class to qml which is the `Base` class but the signal is actually emitted in derived class. Should the signal be also virtual by any chance? How should I receive this signal in QML?

Comment: You put the Derived instance as target. (Also you forgot the Q_OBJECT macro for Derived)

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld but the derived class is internal part of the model, it not directly exposed but maybe I need to expose it?

Answer (score 1):

The MOC is the one who implements the function (your signal) `void somethingChanged();`.

An example could look like this in the `moc_XYZ.cpp` file.

```
// SIGNAL 13
void Derived::doSomething()
{
    QMetaObject::activate(this, &staticMetaObject, 13, Q_NULLPTR);
}
```

So how do you make the MOC happy?

Add `Q_OBJECT` in your `derived.h`

Answer (score 0):

In order to create interfaces to be used in Qt I have found two cases:

1. Based on QObject

This is the most easy form, and you are in the right way. Just create a class based on QObject with abstract methods and declare signals. Derived classes must not declare the signals again, just emit them when needed.

This is your case. MOC generator need to know that `Base` interface has an signal and it can be emitted. Just declare signals in `Base` instead derived classes.

2. Pure virtual class (extra info)

Sometimes you need to derive from any QObject-based class (e.g. *QAbstractListModel*) but it need to implement some interfaces too. C++ allows multiple inheritance, but Qt doesn't like classes that derive from two or more QObject-based classes.
So you should create a *plain* pure virtual class, and declare signals as any other unimplemented method.

```
// Base  
class Base
{
public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base(); 

    virtual void doSomething() = 0;

signals:
    virtual void somethingChanged() = 0;

};
```

Now, derive from Base and declare the signal again:

```
// Derived
class Derived : public QObject, public Base
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Derived(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Derived();

    //Implmetations of Base methods
public:
    void doSomething();

    //Declaration of Base signals
signals:
    void somethingChanged();

}
```